# Run a CodeIgniter project in Ubuntu

Tags: php, codeigniter, ubuntu

I have an existing project in Codeigniter in my windows environment and I recently switched to Ubuntu, the LAMP stack is already installed by whenever I enter "http://192.168.8.109/consultation/" or "http://localhost/consultation/" the 404 from CodeIgniter appears. I think the problem is that it cannot read any controller from the project.

Comment: Try access `http://localhost`. Does it work?

Comment: Doesn't work. I tried installing another codeigniter repo to check if hte problem is in my project. The welcome page works but when I create my custom controller it returns 404. I think the problem is returning the custom controller.

Comment: must start with Uppercase letter..for ex:: Controller.php

Comment: First make sure you have set your base url in config.php example `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/yourproject/';` **then make sure only the first letter only of file and class names upper case the rest lower case.**

Comment: Ubuntu requires the .htaccess file in the root folder of a project with Rewrite mode on for run CodeIgniter project.

Comment: @GopalBhuva it worked! Thank you. I'm so clumsy -_-

Comment: Glad to know! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
is your localhost is working ? 
 if not then you have to make an entry into hosts file.
open terminal with super user like this type ctrl + alt + t(terminal) and 
type gedit /etc/hosts then enter 127.0.0.1   localhost
```

also check in your url like http://localhost/dashboard/projectname